How do I keep a datetime field in ASP.NET null
I have a datetime field in a gridview.
I need the date field to be null or empty if the database returns either null, "", or 1/1/0001.
How does one achieve this? I seem to be having a brain freeze.
You can see what I have tried here:
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastEval" ItemStyle-CssClass="gvColumnSmallCss">
  <ItemTemplate >
    <asp:Label ID="lblmyLabel"  Text='<%# Bind("myField","{0:M/d/yyyy}") %>'  runat="server" > </asp:Label>  
                                
    <%--    Text= '  <%#  Eval("myField") !=null ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myField")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "" %>'
                          --%>
    <%-- Text='<%# Bind("myField","{0:M/d/yyyy}") %>'--%>
   </ItemTemplate>

C# code:
protected void gv_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    string myField;
    myField= (e.Row.FindControl("lblmyField") as Label).Text;
    DateTime? myField= null;
    _myField = string.IsNullOrEmpty(myField)
                     ? (DateTime?)null 
                     : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(myField);
   
    DateTime checkDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/00001");
    
    if (lastEval == checkDate.ToString() || myField=="")
    {
      (e.Row.FindControl("lblmyField") as Label).Text = "";
    }
  }
}

I also tried similar in the RowDataBound handler method.

Please use proper casing and format your code. The better, the more likely someone feels like wanting to help you.

string myField;     myField= (e.Row.FindControl("lblmyField") as Label).Text;     DateTime? myField= null; <- This shouldn't even compile (duplicate name). Is it a copy&paste error?

"DateTime? myField= null; <- This shouldn't even compile. Is it a copy&paste error?"   what do you mean?   DateTime? myField= null;  is how you can set a datetime to null

Yes but right above it, you declare another var of type string with the same name. That doesn't work.

oh that was a typo

what is populating the GridView? List or DataTable/DataSet?

Do this in SELECT command pulling data from database.

A real date field should not be able to return an empty string. If it can, that's a seriously flawed schema design. Since Eval() returns Object rather than string, if you have to call Convert.ToDateTime() on the result of Eval("myField"), rather than merely casting, that is also a likely sign of a seriously flawed schema design.

I solved it as follows  incase anyone has a similar problem:
          <asp:Label ID="lblmyLabel" Text= '<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myField")) !=  Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001") ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("myField")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "" %>'  runat="server" > </asp:Label>  


Better to use a helper function than add logic in the markup.
markup
<asp:Label ID="lblEvalDate" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# CheckEvalDate(Eval("EvalDate")) %>'>
</asp:Label>

code-behind
protected string CheckEvalDate(object dt)
{
    DateTime evalDate;
    if (dt == DBNull.Value || !DateTime.TryParse(dt.ToString(), out evalDate))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return evalDate == DateTime.MinValue ?
        string.Empty : evalDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
}

